# How do I compute the sum of a count column in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to compute the sum of a column which counts values of another number column. The specific column I want to compute the sum of is 'COUNT(d.totalcostofrent).

I just can't get the sum to show up under the table at all!

Here is my code:

```
COLUMN dummy NOPRINT
COMPUTE SUM OF totalcostofrent ON DUMMY
BREAK ON dummy
COLUMN branchname HEADING 'Branch Name'
COLUMN "Revenue" HEADING 'Rental Revenue' FORMAT $99,999

select null dummy,
       a.branchname,
       count(c.rentalid) "Number of Rentals",
       SUM(d.totalcostofrent) "Revenue"
from   branch a
 inner join branchstaffrole b on a.branchid = b.branchid
 inner join rental c on b.staffid = c.branchstaffid
 inner join rentaltool d on c.rentalid = d.rentalid
where  to_char(d.DATEOUT, 'YYYY') = '&Year'
group  by a.branchname
order  by 4 DESC;


Branch Name          Number of Rentals Rental Revenue
-------------------- ----------------- --------------
Lichfield                            2           $120
Stoke-on-Trent                       3           $140
Birmingham                           3           $155
Stafford                             3           $225
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Branch Name          Number of Rentals Rental Revenue
-------------------- ----------------- --------------
Lichfield                            2           $120
Stoke-on-Trent                       3           $140
Birmingham                           3           $155
Stafford                             3           $225
                                                 ____
Sum                                              $640
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't understand the question.. Can you give an example of the results you are getting now as well as what you are looking for?

Comment: I have just updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to format the report with SQL*Plus commands.  You are really close, only you have an alias for the column: SUM(d.totalcostofrent) "Revenue".  So you need to use that alias in your Compute SQL*Plus command as well:

```
COMPUTE SUM OF "Revenue" ON DUMMY
```

This will return:

```
Branch Name    Number of Rentals Rental Revenue
-------------- ----------------- --------------
Lichfield                      2           $120
Birmingham                     3           $155
Stoke-on-Trent                 3           $140
Stafford                       3           $225
                                 --------------
                                           $640
```

You can also do the same excluding the dummy column with:

```
COMPUTE SUM OF "Revenue" ON REPORT
BREAK ON REPORT
COLUMN branchname HEADING 'Branch Name'
COLUMN "Revenue" HEADING 'Rental Revenue' FORMAT $99,999
```

Which returns:

```
Branch Name    Number of Rentals Rental Revenue
-------------- ----------------- --------------
Lichfield                      2           $120
Birmingham                     3           $155
Stoke-on-Trent                 3           $140
Stafford                       3           $225
                                 --------------
sum                                        $640
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ROLLUP` extension to extend the aggregation function (e.g. `count`) to higher level groups:

```
group by rollup(a.branchname)
```

See [this reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1007413).

Comment: This should just be: "group by rollup(a.branchname)".  How you have it written with throw an error.  A great option for returning the TOTAL row from the SQL itself though.

Comment: Yes I tried this which worked but unfortunately didn't split away from the last row which didn't make it clear that it was a total. Thanks though, I'll be able to use this somewhere else.